# Web server ignores savepath and saves to wwwroot, while localhost works perfectly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I try to use FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath), it works very strangely.

When using localhost, it uses the savePath perfectly. I have used a variety of paths and syntaxes to confirm this. However, when I publish this to my website, and use the upload feature there, it saves the file to the wwwroot folder, and nowhere else.

In fact, no matter what the path is specified, it ALWAYS saves to wwwroot, even when I tell it otherwise.

```
Sub SaveFile(ByVal file As HttpPostedFile)

    ' Specify the path to save the uploaded file to.
    Dim savePath As String = Server.MapPath("\uploads\")

    ' Get the name of the file to upload.
    Dim fileName As String = FileUpload1.FileName

    ' Create the path and file name to check for duplicates.
    Dim pathToCheck As String = savePath + fileName

    ' Create a temporary file name to use for checking duplicates.
    Dim tempfileName As String

    ' Check to see if a file already exists with the
    ' same name as the file to upload.        
    If (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck)) Then
        Dim counter As Integer = 2
        While (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
            ' If a file with this name already exists,
            ' prefix the filename with a number.
            tempfileName = counter.ToString() + fileName
            pathToCheck = savePath + tempfileName
            counter = counter + 1
        End While

        fileName = tempfileName

        ' Notify the user that the file name was changed.
        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "A file with the same name already exists." + "<br />" + _
                                 "Your file was saved as " + fileName

    Else

        ' Notify the user that the file was saved successfully.
        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was uploaded successfully."

    End If

    ' Append the name of the file to upload to the path.
    savePath += fileName

    ' Call the SaveAs method to save the uploaded
    ' file to the specified directory.
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath)

End Sub
```

Once I get through this problem, I would like the path to be going to a virtual directory, which I have already created through IIS, but because of this problem, I can not test it.

Comment: Is this Classic asp or asp.net.  If you're using vb.net rather than vbscript then it's vb.net

Comment: It is asp.net and vb.net. I just put asp as the tag, and it must have filled in classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the changes to the upload process were not being fully changed unless I deleted the files in root, and republished them. Publishing the changes without deleting the initial files did not fix the upload process. Still somewhat mysterious, but at least I found a hard fix to the problem. Likely a change is made in web.config, or another file, which causes the changes to not fully occur unless a fresh start was made.

Answer (score 0):

would it work like,

```
Dim savePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/")
```

just check by changing direction of slash to /

Comment: No, because my problem has little to do with the actual syntax of how I reference the path, but something weird and behind the scenes like permission errors that aren't popping up.